# Decode event data with struct

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, abi

I need to retrieve data to front end from event:

```
eventSignature: 'ProposalIsCreated(bytes32,address,address,address,string,uint256,uint256,bytes32))'
```

I use defaultAbiCoder from ethers.js and this function throws an error, probably because I use array syntax, but I have no other ideas how to represent struct and make it work:

```
ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(
    [
      "bytes32",
      "address",
      ["address", "address", "string", "uint256", "uint256", "bytes32"],
    ],
    event.data
  );
```

Data example:

```
"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"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it this way your

```
//rpc
const connection = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com/', { chainId: 80001 });

//set address
let contractAddress = "address";
   //set private-key
   const privateKey="key";
 
 //connect wallet
 var signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, connection)
 //create signer
 const txSigner = contract.connect(signer);

 //instance of struct
 const Ranger = "(uint256 idNumber,uint256 dateOfBirth,string lastName,string userAddress,string gender,string  firstName,string middleName,uint256 accountNumber,bool isActive,uint256 phone; )";

//human readable abi
const ABI = [
 `function addRanger(uint256 _id,string _userAdd,string  _gender,uint256 _dob,uint _phone,string _middleName,string _firstName,string _lastName,uint256  _account) public`,
`function getAllUsers() public`,
`event AddedRanger(${Ranger}  created)`];

 //create contract instance
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ABI, connection);

 contract.on("AddedRanger",(Ranger,event) => {
        console.log({
            value: Ranger.toString(),
            data: event
        });
    });
```